# iSCSI on startup

Tags: linux, centos, storage, iscsi

I've configure iSCSI but CentOS 6.3 is unable to recognize if on startup.

Here is fstab config:

```
/dev/sdb1               /home                   ext4    _netdev         0 0
```

Here is iscsi.conf settings:

```
node.startup = automatic
node.session.auth.username = 
node.session.auth.password =
discovery.sendtargets.auth.username =
discovery.sendtargets.auth.password =
```

Here is initiatorname.iscsi:
    iqn.2004-04.com.iscsi:iscsi:iscsi.start.8cff69

Here is chkconfig:

```
iscsid          0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

Any help please.

dmesg is not showing errors. 
My question is that centos 6.3 is unable to initialize and boot with iscsi. I've to process it manually. 
Yes both iscsi and iscsid are enabled on start up.
How can i check / configure initramfs .. any manual?

Comment: have you check dmesg and /var/log/messages for errors?

Comment: What is your question? What is the problem you are having?

Comment: what about `iscsi` service? is it enabled in startup ?

Comment: Is your initramfs configured to include iSCSI support? On Ubuntu I know I need to configure this for any network device on boot.

Comment: dmesg is not showing errors.
yes both iscsi and iscsid are enabled on startup

Comment: dmesg is not showing errors.
my question is that centos 6.3 is unable to initialize and boot with iscsi. I've to process it manually.
yes both iscsi and iscsid are enabled on startup
how can i check / configure initramfs .. any manual?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused: Do you need the iSCSI disk for booting?  Or is this 'just' something which comes later (during service startup) e.g. to add an iSCSI disk for /home?

Comment: to add an iSCSI disk for /home

Comment: Any one please help in this regard.